# $key iniciando por 1

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal, como inicio um $key de um foreach por 1?

```
foreach ($dados as $key => $reg) {
$table .= '<tr>
           <td width="3%">' . $key . '</td>
           <td width="18%">' . $reg['nome_clientet'] . '</td>
</tr>';
```

Está iniciando por zero, gostaria de iniciar a partir de '1';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que o 1 seria mais na exibição, pois está colocando na tabela entao usar um +1 resolveria o print.

```
foreach ($dados as $key => $reg) {
    $newKey = $key +1;
    $table .= '<tr>
           <td width="3%">' . $newKey . '</td>
           <td width="18%">' . $reg['nome_clientet'] . '</td>
</tr>';
```

Logo, você usaria o `$newKey` no prints e o `$key` no backend.

Ou para o array realmente começar  do zero deve funcionar assim:

```
array_push($array[0], $array); #adiciona o primeiro elemento como ultimo (para nao perder dados)
unset($array[0]); #apaga primeiro elemento do array.
```

Comment: Exatamente isso cara. Obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode recortar o array primeiro antes de entrar no foreach.

```
$reg = array_slice($reg, 1);
foreach ($dados as $key => $reg) {
    $table .= '<tr>
           <td width="3%">' . $key . '</td>
           <td width="18%">' . $reg['nome_clientet'] . '</td>
    </tr>';
```

Comment: remover o primeiro resultado não causará perda de dados?

Comment: Não funciona assim Euler